# Apache Spark: issue with filter()

Tags: python, twitter, apache-spark, pyspark

​Hi all !

I'm working on a tweets database to perform sentiment analysis, and I have a problem with Spark's method filter()​.

I need first to separate the positive (first field = 4) and the negative tweets (first field = 0)

```
def parseLine(line):
    fields=line.split(",")
    return (fields[0], fields[5].encode("utf8"))

data = sc.textFile("path\\training_sent140.csv")
dataRDD = data.map(parseLine)
dataRDD.first() #OK
dataRDDneg = dataRDD.filter(lambda x:"0" in x[0])
dataRDDneg.first() #OK
```

`dataRDDneg = dataRDD.filter(lambda x:"0" in x[0])`​ is working fine for me​.

But when I try to do the same for positive tweets, it returns an error

```
dataRDDpos = dataRDD.filter(lambda x:"4" in x[0])​
​dataRDDpos.first() #not Ok
```

> #### error:
>
> 16/03/08 10:42:21 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for py
>   thon
>   java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
>          at java.net.Socket.shutdownOutput(Socket.java:1496)
>          at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$
>   $anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:288)
>          at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$
>   $anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonRDD.scala:288)
>          at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3$
>   $anonfun$apply$2.apply(PythonRDD.scala:288)
>          at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLog(Utils.scala:1754)
>          at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.
>   apply(PythonRDD.scala:288)
>          at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1741)
>          at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.s
>   cala:239)

Can you help me ?

Comment: Could you provide complete traceback including Python exception? It is most likely a matter of malformed data not filter.